# what type of information does remote repositories sites may contain and how to access keychain data?

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

So today I was installing sourcetree on my macbook, and I came across few prompts while source tree setup was registering with Atlassian's bitbucket so it prompted this .

[image]

So I want to know what is the information being access and how is it access, If I am not wrong I can use the same keychain data to allow the user to use email address to be able to send mail with registered email without having to enter password!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be similar to what the [GitHub page illustrates](https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain):

- host
- protocol
- username
- password

You can launch the keychain (after allowing SourceTree to store your credentials), and check its content.

[image: https://github-images.s3.amazonaws.com/help/setup/keychain-access.png]

The [OP san](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1622400/san) adds:

> I found it in the keychain: I didn't had **`All Items`** selected.

Comment: in keychain access, I followed as ggithub Page u suggested but there is no entry by github.com keychain , so what was source tree was accessing from ?

Comment: @san why are you looking for a github entry? The GitHub page was just an example to *illustrate* the keychain GUI. But if you are using SourceTree with a repo in bitbucket, you should be looking for a `bitbucket.org` entry.

Comment: even entring `bitbucket ` returns no result for me!  could it be retrieving keychain data from the website?

Comment: @san but did you allow SourceTree to store your credentials? And did you enter those credentials at any point in time? In other words, did you do a `git push` since allowing those credentials to be stored in the keychain? The idea is: it will then *ask* for your credentials *once*, then store them and reuse them for the rest of the session.

Comment: well if you see the prompt image I posted it is asking to access the information and not storing the information, I too want to access the information most whether it is stored locally or on bitbucket website

Comment: @san It will be stored locally, in your local keychain.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47083/discussion-between-san-and-vonc)